# Eclipse has two C/C++ indexers (fast & full): what's the difference?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, indexer

Eclipse CDT provides two indexers for C/C++ code (Preferences > C/C++ > Indexer).  Does anybody know what the exact difference is between these two?

The help file isn't exactly enlightening:

> "CDT supports the contribution of
>   additional indexers, with 2 indexers
>   being provided with the default CDT
>   release:
>
> - Fast C/C++ Indexer : provides fastest indexing capabilities - both
>     declarations and cross reference
>     information. This is the recommended
>     indexer.
> - Full C/C++ Indexer : provides even more accurate indexing
>     capabilities at the cost of
>     performance - both declarations and
>     cross reference information."

What does it mean to be more *accurate*: does it index more things, and if so which ones?

Comment: Is it still the case, in Eclipse Kepler, of there being two indexers available? I don't see two... perhaps one has been removed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from the CDT page describing their parsing and indexing([CDT/designs/Overview of Parsing](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/designs/Overview_of_Parsing)).  It gives a pretty good description of what the differences are and where the fast indexer can fail:

> Parsing and binding resolution is a
>   slow process, this is a problem
>   because the user expects code editing
>   features such as content assist to be
>   fast. For this reason CDT stores
>   binding information in an on-disk
>   cache called “the index” or “the PDOM”
>   (Persisted Document Object Model) in
>   order to be able to provide features
>   that respond quickly to user requests.
>
> Building the index involves parsing
>   all the code in a project, resolving
>   all the bindings and writing those
>   bindings to the index. The index is
>   then incrementally updated every time
>   the user edits a file.
>
> Older versions of CDT support three
>   different indexing modes, fast
>   indexing, full indexing and no
>   indexing. The default setting being
>   the fast indexer because indexing a
>   large project can be a time consuming
>   process. The difference between the
>   fast and full indexers is that the
>   fast indexer will skip header files
>   that have already been parsed once,
>   while the full indexer will always
>   re-parse a header file every time it
>   is included. However it is important
>   to understand that the full indexer,
>   despite its name, is still not fully
>   accurate.
>
> When a header file is included in a
>   source file it is subject to any
>   macros that have been defined at that
>   point. Some library headers use macros
>   in conjunction with preprocessor
>   conditionals (#ifdefs) to partially
>   include a header file. Sometimes such
>   a header file is included more than
>   once in a project, if the macros that
>   the header depends on are different
>   each time the header is included then
>   different parts of the header may be
>   included in different source files.
>   Neither indexer will be accurate in
>   this scenario because it will only
>   index the header the first time it is
>   encountered.
>
> The Full indexer will re-parse headers
>   it has already encountered, but it
>   will not re-index them. Therefore
>   source files that include a header may
>   be parsed more accurately, but the
>   header itself will only be indexed the
>   one time. The full indexer is much
>   slower than the fast indexer because
>   of the extra parsing it does, but it
>   is only marginally more accurate. For
>   this reason the Full indexer is not
>   recommended and has been removed from
>   the current version of CDT.
>
> Each project has a single PDOM
>   associated with it. The PDOM is stored
>   on disk as a flat binary file. The
>   indexer will only index headers that
>   are included by source files, so if
>   there is a .h file in the project that
>   is not being included by any .c or
>   .cpp file, then normally it won’t get
>   indexed. However there is a preference
>   setting for indexing all files in the
>   project.

Comment: I wrote that Wiki page entry, and re-reading it here I've realized it was wrong. The Full indexer is not actually fully accurate and has been removed from the current version of CDT. I've updated the wiki and this answer to be correct (and I've double checked with other CDT developers to make sure its correct).

Comment: @MikeKucera everyone I know who uses eclipse uses an old version so that they can get the full indexer, do you know if it will ever return to current versions?

Comment: We don't even call the remaining indexer the 'fast' indexer anymore, since there has only been one indexer for years now we just started calling it 'the indexer'. It has gotten many accuracy and speed improvements lately. For example the indexer will now index a header file multiple times if it is included more than once in different contexts (ie different sets of significant macros). That gets you back a lot of the accuracy that the old full indexer had without the huge performance penalty. I highly recommend that you and your friends upgrade to the latest version of CDT.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it always reparses any found/included files without "caching". The reason if that the contents of the files might depend on the preprocessor definitions so it is always reparsed. Fast parser assumes nothing has changed since the file was first encountered.

(but I could be wrong)

Answer (score 1):

> Does anybody know what the exact difference is between these two?

In my experience, about 32MB heap.