# Does Bada IDE have code completion and meaningful error messages?

Tags: c++, syntax, code-completion, bada

I'm trying to upgrade a Bada app from 1.2 to 2.0 with no experience of Bada. I have the project building and can run it in the emulator but I get a load of warnings and I cant click the text boxes to get a keyboard and enter anything in the emulator.

Unfortunately the warning messages are completely cryptic to me, for example

```
SearchForm::SearchForm(void) :
```

gives the warning message "when initialized here"

What when initialized here??!!

Also, all the TryCatch statements show syntax error, and nothing I have found on the internet seems to make it happy:

```
result OnDraw()
{
    result r = E_SUCCESS;

    Canvas* readerCanvas = GetCanvasN();
    TryCatch(E_SUCCESS == GetLastResult(), "Failed to get canvas: %S", GetErrorMessage(r));

     if (readerCanvas)
     {
         Rectangle tempRect(0, 0, GetBounds().width, GetBounds().height);
         Point tempPoint(0, 0);
         r = readerCanvas->Copy(tempPoint, *iDrawingCanvas, tempRect);
         TryCatch(E_SUCCESS == r, "Failed to copy canvas: %S", GetErrorMessage(r));
         delete readerCanvas;
     }

    return r;

    CATCH:
        delete readerCanvas;
        return r;
}
```

The TryCatch line says "statement has no effect", if I try edit it to match the examples I'v found I get a syntax error.

What's up with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to outdo your IDE's supposed bad messages by quoting them entirely out of context and only partially. Let me break it down:

#### TryCatch

The macro is defined as

```
TryCatch(condition, cleanup, message)
```

When the condition is evaluated to false, this will goto CATCH. You could think of the macro like this:

```
if (!condition)
{
    goto CATCH;
}
```

For example, you can use it like this:

```
void TryCatchDemo::UseTryCatch(void)
{
    TryCatch(1==2, , "1 is NOT 2");

    AppLog("This should not appear");

    CATCH:
        AppLog("Catch block");
}
```

Now, your second parameter is a string literal, `"Failed to get canvas: %S"`, which unsurprisingly, doesn't have an effect when used as statement:

```
    "does nothing";
    123;              // just like this
```

So the compiler is being nice to warn you of the fact that you probably had something else in mind. Note also, that *`statement has no effect`* is **not** a syntax error.

### "when initialized here"

Know your language! The code quoted isn't legal C++ to begin with:

```
  SearchForm::SearchForm(void) :
```

At best this is the beginning of a constructor definition, with a missing initializer list and body. In the C++ language spec, class members are initialized in the order in which they were *declared*, not in the order in which they appear in the initializer list. A minimal example:

```
struct X
{
     int a, b;
     X() : b(), a() {}
};
```

This results in the compiler warning:

```
/tmp/test.cpp|3 col 13| warning: ‘X::b’ will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
/tmp/test.cpp|3 col 10| warning:   ‘int X::a’ [-Wreorder]
/tmp/test.cpp|4 col 6| warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
```

As you can see, you not only clipped the code but also the warnings! If you read the whole message and the whole code, the fix would be pretty obvious:

```
struct X
{
     int a, b;
     X() : a(), b() {}
};
```

**Bonus**: In case you were wondering, why the ordering matters, consider what happens when you do:

```
struct X
{
     int a, b;
     X() : b(), a(b) {} // OOPS!
};
```

Hope this helps

### Using a Format String with the Macros

**Edit** I just noted this: it is probably not supported to use format strings inside the Try/Catch macros:

> Each of the macros that support a message parameters actually support format strings. A format string is similar to the format string of printf **on systems that support it (bada does NOT support it)**

Comment: Thanks for the response, let me clarify. I didn't "clip" any part of the warnings, I get them by mousing over the highlighted lines, I was unaware a single error would be split and so I'd have to look elsewhere (console?). As for the syantax of the tryCatch, the reason I am confused (aside from the fact I'v never developed for Bada, and my C++ is rusty, is that, I was given this project which is working and released on Bada 1.2 and asked to update to 2.0. I should assume the syntax and code is correct. Your note on format strings in try/catch macros would indicate it is not.

Comment: @Hamid: I'd take some time to allow for the learning curve. You should be able to find the full messages in the IDE's output pane (I don't have the IDE, but you can probably find it on your own :)). (C++ compiler messages never do work well in mouse-over/balloon tips. That isn't really specific to any compiler, IDE or library.)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, I'm not being allowed the time for the learning curve, which is why I'm trying to get the necessary understanding of the platform so I can jump right in and get my job done.  My last question really is, where's the code completion, does it exist or is that wishful thinking for Bada/C++ (Bada IDE).

Comment: @Hamid: it should be supported: [The bada IDE is based on the Eclipse CDT (C/C++ Development Tools). Eclipse provides a set of code editing tools in its text editor. These tools support CDT features, such as syntax highlighting, code folding, tabbed documents, and content assistance (context-sensitive code completion).](http://static.bada.com/contents/docs/resources_0818/com.osp.devguide.help/html/gettingstarted/bada_sdk/bada_ide/bada_ide.htm)

Comment: Perhaps you need to enable indexing in the CDT project options? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763837/eclipse-has-two-c-c-indexers-fast-full-whats-the-difference

Comment: Thanks, according to the settings, it is enabled already. But I get no content assist of any kind, it's a bit of a pain, especially when writing for a platform I don't know, that I have to click build before I can know if a piece of code I write is correct or not, like a method name, or some other simple input.