# Eclipse C/C++ indexer

Tags: java, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-indigo, indexer

I am working on Eclipse IDE for Java (Indigo). My project is using CDT in addition to Java source. I frequently get this error message from Eclipse, although everything works fine.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV9Ep.jpg]

What is C/C++ indexer? What is the actual source of this error and how to remove it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763837/eclipse-has-two-c-c-indexers-fast-full-whats-the-difference explains what is eclipse indexer. Try using another indexer (fast or full)

Comment: That looks like internal bug in CDT. Send it to bugs.eclipse.org, and also attach your eclipse log file. (You can export it from Eclipse from Error Log view).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C/C++ indexer parses your source code file to gather information used for auto completion, syntax highlight and so on.

You said you are using CDT *in addition* to Java source. Sounds to me as if you are using C/C++ and Java code in the *same* Eclipse Project. My guess would be that the C/C++ indexer accidentally tries to parse a Java source file and is confused. If so, use different Eclipse projects for your Java and for your C/C++ code.