# eclipse fails to include some enumerations from include files

Tags: c++, linux, build, ide

I have been using the Indigo release for some time.  I keep having a reoccuring problem with enumerations defined in include files not working.  The IDE reports the symbole can't be resolved but if I copy it to the file it complains about a conflict.

This shows that it does indeed resolve it but doesn't like it for some reason.

I really hate having to code the same enumeration in many different files.  Isn't that what includes are all about?

Comment: Have you tried updating / installing Juno? Logging a bug?

Comment: Can you show a code example. Did you try rerunning the indexer?

Comment: It takes time to index things, that's why it finds it only the second time.

Comment: BTW if the IDE marks the symbol as not resolved, that doesn't mean your code won't compile correctly. That's two separate pair of shoes. You shouldn't modify your code, to get IDE (indexer) errors go away.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/774914/132847

After that, you should:

1. check your CDT's C++ Indexer configuration. (I don't know what is the size of your project, but it might help to increase your cache's size.)
2. Add your headers' directories to the include path in the eclipse's project configuration (if they are not part of your project) this way:

   > Select “Project > Properties” from the menu. A dialog comes up. In the
   >   tree on the left open: “C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols”.

   [image: http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/images/c_paths.png]

   > Add your header files' path to the include path

Good luck,

Tal